# Is there a way to retrieve the PHPDoc comment of a class constant?

Tags: php, phpdoc

I have the following code in PHP:

```
abstract class ProjectVars
{
    /**
     * Defines whether a user is logged in as ...
     */
    const loggedInAs = [...];

    [...]
}
```

I would like to access the string `Defines whether a user is logged in as ...`. Obviously there are more constants and I would like to get the string of all constants.
Is that possible? With reflection classes, I can use

```
$rc = new ReflectionClass('ProjectVars');
var_dump($rc->getDocComment());
```

to get the PHPDoc comment for the whole class. I didn't find an according method for reading the PHPDoc of a class constant. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is: using the Reflection API like you already know but then you might take it a bit further by creating a function that would output all the comments. 
This approach, however, simply create a Static Method within the Class in Question that would be called statically another way is to create a simple helper class with just one Static method which takes an Argument (the name of the Class). The Code below demonstrates both approaches:

```
    <?php

        abstract class ProjectVars {
            /**
             * Defines whether a user is logged in as ...
             */
            protected $loggedIn;

            /**
             * Determines whether the user is registered or not
             * @var bool;
             */
            protected $register;

            /**
             * Holds information about user's surfing/visit history
             * @var string;
             */
            protected $records;




            public static function getClassComments(){
                $refClass           = new ReflectionClass(self::class);
                $comments           = array();

                foreach ($refClass->getProperties() as &$refProperty) {
                    $comments[$refProperty->getName()]  =  trim(preg_replace("#((\/)?(\*{1,2})(\/)?)#si", "", $refProperty->getDocComment()));
                }
                return $comments;
            }
        }


        var_dump(ProjectVars::getClassComments());
        // PRODUCES:    
        array (size=3)
          'loggedIn' => string 'Defines whether a user is logged in as ...' (length=42)
          'register' => string 'Determines whether the user is registered or not
                  @var bool;' (length=63)
          'records' => string 'Holds information about user's surfingvisit history
                  @var string;' (length=68)
```

Thus to access all the comments for a Property say: `loggedIn` or `register` or `records`, all you may have to do is something like this:

```
                 ProjectVars::getClassComments()['loggedIn'];
                 ProjectVars::getClassComments()['register'];
                 ProjectVars::getClassComments()['records'];
```

**2ND APPROACH: USING A SIMPLE, HELPER CLASS**

```
    <?php

        class CommentAnalyser{

            public static function getClassCommentsFor($fullyQualifiedClassName){
                $refClass           = new ReflectionClass($fullyQualifiedClassName);
                $comments           = array();

                foreach ($refClass->getProperties() as &$refProperty) {
                    $comments[$refProperty->getName()]  =  trim(preg_replace("#((\/)?(\*{1,2})(\/)?)#si", "", $refProperty->getDocComment()));
                }
                return $comments;
            }
        }


        var_dump(CommentAnalyser::getClassCommentsFor('ProjectVars'));
        // PRODUCES:    
        array (size=3)
          'loggedIn' => string 'Defines whether a user is logged in as ...' (length=42)
          'register' => string 'Determines whether the user is registered or not
                  @var bool;' (length=63)
          'records' => string 'Holds information about user's surfingvisit history
                  @var string;' (length=68)
```

Mock Up [HERE](https://eval.in/606883).

Cheers and Good-Luck...

Comment: Just a small note: the replace regex devoured the slash in "surfing/visit".

Comment: @RuslanBes Thanks Mate.... You are right ...see to that in a moment... but you get the Idea... ;-)